# Flutter Daemon, How to get 'appId'

Tags: flutter

I'm finally able to send the Flutter Daemon a request
and I want to be able to send an app.restart command,
but it needs the 'appId'.

I've looked at the Flutter Daemon docs, and it looks like
certain commands can return events that have the 'appId'
but you need one to send the request.

And I've looked all over, tried several things, and
can't find the 'appId' anywhere.

I saw something where it looked like this:

```
"appId":"dcfa8cd3-cd56-460f-b09a-20fd329606e2"
```

How can I get it programmatically?

The Flutter Daemon docs where not that helpful on that.

I have to be able to do it using Java, and not Dart,
and I'm doing it on Windows, and not using Android Studio
or other IDE.

UPDATE:

Do you generate your own UUID and then add it to
the pubspec.yaml?

I found this:
"In your pubspec, add an entry for dart-uuid to your dependencies"

???:

```
dependencies:
 uuid: dcfa8cd3-cd56-460f-b09a-20fd329606e2
```

Does the UUID need to be a certain "type", v1, v3 or v5
and have certain information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally figured it out.

You have to run 'flutter run --machine'
and in the resulting events, it'll have the
'appId' of the started app:

[{"event":"daemon.connected","params":{"version":"0.4.2","pid":3196}}]
[{"event":"app.start","params":{"appId":"9e863256-cf50-4cc9-8585-8b339af07db8","
deviceId":"emulator-5554","directory":"C:\Android\Dev\flutter_test_uuid","sup
portsRestart":true}}]

I wish there was an alternative way to get it though.